# how to insert an object into the list in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

**from**

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "message": "Success",
    "data": [
        {
            "order": {
                "id_biling": "1",
                "order_id": "A18",
                "kd_bill": "001001202101200001",
                "order_name": "Kita",
                "amount": "20000"
            },
            "detail": [
                {
                    "kd_bill": "001001202101200001",
                    "name": "Odading",
                    "id_item": "66",
                    "amount": "10000",
                    "subtot": "20000",
                    "jml": "2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**to this**

```
 {
    "status": 1,
    "message": "Success",
    "data": [
        {
            "order": {
                "id_biling": "1",
                "order_id": "A18",
                "kd_bill": "001001202101200001",
                "order_name": "Kita",
                "amount": "20000",
"detail": [
                    {
                        "kd_bill": "001001202101200001",
                        "name": "Odading",
                        "id_item": "66",
                        "amount": "10000",
                        "subtot": "20000",
                        "jml": "2"
                    }
                ]
            }
            
        }
    ]
}
```

**mycode**

```
        $output = [];
        foreach($listorder->result() as $id){
```

$data['order'] = $this->db->query("SELECT a.`id_biling`,a.`order_id`,a.kd_bill,a.`order_name`,a.`amount` from `pos_biling_kasir` a left join pos_ref_tenant b on a.`id_tenant`=b.`id` where a.kd_bill='".$id->kd_bill."'")->row();

$data['detail'] = $this->db->query('SELECT *,sum(a.amount) as subtot,count(a.id_item) as jml from (select a.`kd_bill`,b.`name`,a.id_item,a.amount from `pos_transaction_tenant` a left join `pos_ref_item` b on a.`id_item`=b.`id` where a.`kd_bill`='.$id->kd_bill.' ) a group by a.name')->result();

```
        array_push($output, $data);
    }

    $jml = $listorder->num_rows();

    
    if($jml > 0){
            $response = [
                    'status' => 1,
                    'message' => 'Success',
                    'data' => $output
                ];
            echo json_encode($response);
        }else{
             $response = [
                    'status' => 0,
                    'message' => 'Failed',
                    'data' => new stdClass()
                    ];
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way to delete **detail** and push as an element inside **order** like below-,

```
$decoded_response = json_decode($response, true);
foreach($decoded_response['data'][0] as $key=>$value){
       if ($key == 'detail'){
           $decoded_response['data'][0]['order'][$key] = $value;
           unset($decoded_response['data'][0][$key]);
       }
}

echo json_encode($decoded_response);
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/u67kE

Comment: Thanks @always sunny for the answer working properly

Comment: i'm sorry @always sunny if I want to get all the index array not only [0] how to do it? thxs

Comment: In that case you can use a counter variable e.g $i=0; above your foreach loop and use that $i in place of 0 inside the loop and increment  by 1 on each iteration